# How to replace one kernel module in the Linux kernel tree

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I would like to update/exchange a single kernel module in a Linux kernel tree that I got from an embedded device vendor (Hardkernel) with the latest version from the Torvalds Linux kernel.

Could someone describe which components I need to edite and exchanged?

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Comment: What distro are you running?

Comment: @NasirRiley my apologies. The distro is Ubuntu 14.04 and the kernel version I'm currently on is 4.9.x. And to the second point, I don't want to compile the same module in addition, I want to actually replace it in the Kernel source that I have.

Answer (score 1):

To load the module at boot, create a conf file in:

`/etc/modules-load.d`

And name it: `module.conf` where module is the one you want to load.

You'll enter the name of the module inside of the file.

Next, blacklist the `cdc_ether` module:

Open:

`/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

(create the file if it doesn't exist) and enter:

`blacklist cdc_ether`

Reboot your system. It will load your module instead of the cdc_ether module.

Comment: Maybe I described my problem in the wrong way. I don't try to add a kernel module on top of my already compiled and installed kernel. I would like to use this git source code (https://github.com/hardkernel/linux) and for instance, replace a driver called "cdc_ether" with the version that is in this kernel source code https://github.com/torvalds/linux . Then recompile and install that edited kernel.

Comment: Gotcha. `cdc_ether` is a kernel module but it is not built into the kernel. I'll update my answer to reflect this.